# Voting stats for "desperate accept" answers

Tags: support, accepted-answer, upvotes, statistics, automatic-deletion

I am looking for voting statistics on the answers to questions that are:

1. Quickly closed (within 1 hour after posting)
2. Have a single answer
3. Aren't eligible for ["roomba deletion"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773) only because of having an accepted answer
   <sub>side note this excludes dupe-closed questions, as roomba ignores these</sub>

I would like to learn how many questions like above are there (including deleted by moderators or by 10Kers) and how many upvotes on answers were cast by users other than the asker.

<sub>The reason why I ask is that I want to understand how much of a "measurable" value is provided by these answers for users (other than asker and answerer, who apparently benefit from accepting by getting +2 and +15 rep). If it turns out that there are lots of upvotes, I'll likely edit or comment that *roomba post* explaining that exclusion of questions with accepted answers is well justified. If there are too little, I'll likely start a crusade to get rid of questions like that. Anything in between is gray area, I want to decide on it after I learn the data.</sub>

Comment: Did you try running an SEDE query?

Comment: @RobertHarvey [SEDE doesn't cover deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se). and of course, it won't tell which upvotes are cast by asker - only developers can access this

Comment: What?  *"Aren't eligible for roomba deletion."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hmm... is it not the case that mere mortals can't run a query to check "how many upvotes on answers were cast by users other than asker"? Otherwise, vote anonymity would be out the window, no?

Comment: @Louis: Why would you need to know that? *"only because of having an accepted answer"*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I explained why I want this: _how much of a "measurable" value is provided by these answers for users (**other than asker and answerer, who apparently benefit** from accept by getting +2 and +15 rep)._

Comment: Yeah, I'm lost.  I have no idea what you're asking.  Offhand, I'd say that whatever correlation you're trying to find does not exist.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what is that you don't understand? Upvotes cast by asker are not interesting (for about the same reasons why their accept ain't interesting - this all is strictly between asker and answerer), I want to learn about upvotes cast by _other_ answer readers

Comment: Find posts that have more than one upvote.  By definition, that upvote is going to come from somewhere else besides the OP.  I don't consider single-voted posts statistically significant anyway.  We don't make any decision on SE on the basis of a single upvote or downvote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey roomba deletion kicks in by criteria laid out in the [linked post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773): _Closed more than 9 days ago
    Not closed as a duplicate
    Score <= 0
    Not locked
    No answers with a score > 0
    No accepted answer
    No pending reopen votes
    No edits in the past 9 days_

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get by relying on my own memory to make any assertion about the rules on SE (complex as they are).

Comment: So once you have this data set you've described, how is it useful (other than satisfying your own personal curiosity)?

Comment: Why do you judge?  It's useful because a 5k member wants to see the data.

Comment: @GayotFow: The data being asked for is not available in SEDE, and it's not free to retrieve it.  Someone at SE is going to have to spend their paid time to get it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if there are lots of upvotes, I'll likely edit or comment that _roomba post_ explaining that exclusion of accepted answers is well justified. If there are too little, I'll likely start a crusade to get rid of questions like that. Anything in between is gray area, I want to decide on it after I learn the data

Comment: @gnat: Thanks.  Put that in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey done: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/254860/revisions

Comment: On the topic of usefulness, I'd think answers that were downvoted by the community and yet were accepted by the asker are stronger evidence that acceptance was done out of desperation. The question currently asks about "how many upvotes", but I'd suggest that the measure to examine should be the question score, after excluding any votes from the asker. (In my mind, "how many upvotes" means counting only the +1 votes.)

Comment: @Louis question score is set by roomba criteria `Score <= 0`. Although I personally share your opinion, I find it difficult to justify in a way that will be widely supported by SO community - that's why the request is limited to really simple case that leaves little room for disagreement

Comment: @gnat I managed to get my wires crossed. I meant to write "the measure to examine should be the *answer* score [not the question score, as I incorrectly wrote], after excluding any votes from the asker".

Comment: @Louis I see. This is also set by roomba criteria `No answers with a score > 0` and, well, your reasoning is what made me request to exclude upvotes by asker: _"how many upvotes on answers were cast by users other than asker"_. I didn't extended it to account for downvotes, again, only to leave as little room for disagreement as possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31357640/1768232

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's grab a sample of questions closed between 30 and 60 days ago. That oughta include most of what you're talking about. On Stack Overflow, there are 21118 of these, including deleted.

Ok, now let's look at the ones that *weren't* deleted by Community, were closed within 1 hour of creation, and currently score <= 0:

- **2983** questions
- **1092** deleted
- **943** with at least one answer (includes deleted)
- **2234** closed as duplicates (yes, some duplicates are also answered and/or deleted)

Right. Now, you're interested in the ones with answers.

- **187** of these questions are *not* closed as duplicates
- **37** are deleted
- **122** have at least one answer scoring > 0
- **83** have an accepted answer
- **107** have at least one answer that would score > 0 even without the asker's vote.

If you're interested in more details on this, [you might as well use SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/307911) - there aren't really that many of these, and hence I'm not going to risk exposing asker votes by breaking this down any further.

My take-away here is that the Roomba can be substantially improved by careful targeting of duplicates, but going after answered (in a sense, upvoted or accepted) questions is probably not worth the risk.

Comment: If this is the case, then I think that it may be ill-advised to modify roomba to specifically target duplicate posts. The duplicates serve to improve google searches overall. If the voting and overall activity of these posts is low, I do not see the benefit of targeting them as a pattern. On the other hand, perhaps you could explain what "careful targeting" would entail, and what steps would be taken to ensure useful signpost duplicates would be retained? Or why they are not useful at all if that is the case.

Comment: as you say, dups are useful as signposts... So if they're not getting any views...

Comment: I am confused, can you help? I just can't see see how SEDE may be of help here, as I ask about _who_ voted ("how many upvotes on answers were cast by users other than asker") - this is not in data dump (and I hope will _never_ be there:). As for keeping "answered" questions, you probably meant to write something else, because _roomba_ deletes these for a few years now, it only keeps when answers have positive score. Guess it's too late to worry about the risk regarding these :)

Comment: I'm going by the Stack Exchange definition of "answered", @gnat: upvoted or accepted.

Comment: @Shog9 - When you replied I upvoted your comment as it made perfect sense. However, thinking back on it, I wonder if it is not a side affect of the duplicate process for the signpost to have low views. If you google for a question and your search would have matched the duplicate, the google search instead shows the parent (open question) in the results. However, the result was only reached due to the child (closed duplicate) question which receives no views if the parent is visited, even though it was the reason for the search result.

Comment: @Shog9 - Here is an example of this happening. The [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290768/1026459) here talks about opening a duplicate on purpose, and one of [the answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291746/1026459) shows that the signpost is being found in the results, but the link in the results goes to the parent (open question).

Comment: I'm not even a little bit worried about dups that redirect, @travis - they have a very low cost for even small potential benefit.

Comment: there may be not that many "desperate accepts" but as I recently learned, their immunity to deletion possibly inspires some folks to intentional abuse by making a convenient bootstrap for the fraud: [Voting rings - how to handle organized groups upvoting each other?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322115/839601)