# A Negative Score Closed Question With a Negative Score Accepted Answer. Will it be deleted?

Tags: support, downvotes, closed-questions, accepted-answer, automatic-deletion

There are a few of these type of questions out there, but I'd thought I'd highlight [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945208/can-i-insert-php-code-into-mysql) as an example.

The question is poor. Not because we haven't got decent code to work with, or it isn't possible, but because the question essentially boils down to, *how do I do this thing that nobody should ever do?* The community agrees with this as the question is now closed and has a negative score.

The question, however, has an answer that, although very much flawed, does attempt to answer the question. The OP accepts the answer (and some people even upvoted the answer) but the answer now has a negative score.

Given that the question is closed and has a negative score, and also given the answer was accepted but also has a negative score, will this question be deleted? If not, why not? Surely a question like this has no real usefulness (other than an example of what not to do).

Comment: Now that you've drawn attention to it... it probably will be.

Comment: Do you mean _automatically deleted_ by a frequently running script, or in long term from community decisions?

Comment: I realise if there is human intervention by a moderator then anything is possible, but I was talking more about the general case of these types of question being deleted over time. The question on its own would have been (or will be) deleted. If it has a negative accepted answer, how does that change things?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Comment: Aaaaaaand it's gone.

Comment: [“desperate accept”...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254860/839601)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated by [Normal Human](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310015/a-negative-score-closed-question-with-a-negative-score-accepted-answer-will-it#comment269793_310015) the Roomba will check if a question is eligible to be deleted.

The question you linked to is deleted now so I made a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K7tw.png) for the less then 10K users.

You'll see the question was closed and had a score of -1 (+1/-2) and the answer was at 0 (+3/-3). I couldn't verify (nor a mod) if the answer was accepted. When you asked your meta question the SO question was 92 days old.

Based on the [roomba rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) it doesn't fall in the RemoveDeadQuestions category, nor in the RemoveAbandonedQuestions category.

Leaves the RemoveAbandonedClosed category.

The question was closed at the day of asking. It probably survived the roomba because one of these criteria wasn't met:

- has a score of 0 or less
- has no answers with a score > 0
- has no accepted answer

The users that delete voted the question within 30 minutes after you posted the meta question probably assumed that waiting for all above mentioned criteria to be come true wasn't worth it.

There are criteria to remove low quality questions after 30 or 365 days and closed questions after 9 days if they meet certain criteria. The most important criteria is the score. This shows again why up voting low quality stuff is bad as it prevents these automatic scripts to work properly.