# Closed question with an accepted self-answer is not deleted automatically

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, self-answer, automatic-deletion

I think we have a potential loophole that stops a closed question being [deleted automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) where the OP has answered and accepted their own answer.

A simple example is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394060/how-to-show-images-on-front-end-using-easy-taxonomy-images-wordpress-plugins). Closed a month ago, negative scored question, zero scored answer. Only the accept mark is preventing the question from being deleted.

Should zero or worse scored answers from the OP be excluded from the accepted answer check when automatically deleting closed questions?

Comment: related: [Voting stats for “desperate accept” answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254860/839601)

Comment: The logic is that an *answered* question shouldn't get deleted. Do you consider it not answered just because the accepted answer came from OP?

Comment: @user000001 Yes, if that answer hasn't got a positive score.

Comment: @worldofjr: But there are many times that correct answers don't get a positive score. The fact that it is accepted is a strong indicator that it works. The system seems to err on the side of caution and tries not to delete things unnecessarily. Now if someone abuses this to prevent his questions from getting deleted, that should be dealt with, but there is no indication of that in this case.

Comment: If this rule would be applied it would get rid of about [2765 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/541050)

Comment: "As such, we dispense with the logic that preserves answers with 1 vote or an accept mark that will stay deletion at 9 days."